# MSM specific config settings

Tags: multi-site-manager, cookies

Is it possible to only target specific MSM sites, as opposed to all sites.

I have two subdomains and a www site using the same MSM installation.

Is it possible to share a cookies between sub1.domain.co.uk and sub2.domain.co.uk but not affect www.domain.co.uk

Basically i want my members to be able to login to sub1 and automatically be logged in for sub2 domains but not www.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `$assign_to_config` array in each site's `index.php` and `admin.php` files to set *some* per-site config items. ([See docs.](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/general/system_configuration_overrides.html#site-index-file))

But you might have better luck using a `switch` statement in your main `config.php` file, e.g.,

```
switch($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])
{
    case 'www.domain.co.uk':
        $config['foo'] = 'bar';
        break;
    case 'sub1.domain.co.uk':
        $config['foo'] = 'baz';
        break;
}
```

For sharing cookies, look at the `$config['multi_login_sites']` variable, e.g.,

```
$config['multi_login_sites'] = 'http://sub1.domain.co.uk|http://sub2.domain.co.uk';
```

Comment: Hi Derek, $config['multi_login_sites'] caused me some problems, whenever i logged into sub1.domain it would redirect to sub2.domain or whichever site i put last when separated bye | << pipe. Have you experienced this before?

Comment: Hmm, I have not. All that setting should do is affect how the cookies are set.